# How to get For Loop to stop after list it runs through reaches blank cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below code is 'printing' even blank cells pulled from the 'POTemplate' tab while executing the below loop.  I'd like it to stop, though, after it finds an empty cell while running through column 3. Not sure where to edit.

```
function Submit() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var orderSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POTemplate");
  var i = 24;
  for(i = 24; i<= 34; i++) {
    var poNO = orderSheet.getRange("h2").getValue();
    var poDate = orderSheet.getRange("h3").getValue();
    var vendor = orderSheet.getRange("c12").getValue();
    var skuNo = orderSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var skuDesc = orderSheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
    var qty = orderSheet.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
    var uom = orderSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    var utCost = orderSheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();
    var extCost = orderSheet.getRange(i, 8).getValue();

    var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("POHistory");
    var nextRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1; 
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 1).setValue(poNO);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 2).setValue(poDate);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 3).setValue(vendor);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 4).setValue(skuNo);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 5).setValue(skuDesc);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 6).setValue(qty);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 7).setValue(uom);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 8).setValue(utCost);
    targetSheet.getRange(nextRow, 9).setValue(extCost);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure about what you're trying to accomplish but, you can test the blank cell condition and use the `continue` to skip one loop of the iteration and jump to the next loop or the `break` statement to end the iteration and proceed to the code after the iteration.

```js
//continue statement

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 3) { console.log("Skipped iteration " + i); continue; }
    console.log('iteration nº' + i);
}
console.log('finish');

//break statement
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i === 3) { console.log("break on iteration " + i); break; }
    console.log('iteration nº' + i);
}

console.log('finish');
```